# Task Scheduler will not work with Access Linked Tables and Run whether user is logged on or not selected

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to move all my vb scripts that refresh my Access Tables and Queries to our new server which I log into remotely.  I have done without problem with most of my scripts however there are a few that will now work and the thing they all have in common is they have linked tables from other Access databases in them.  I run a script to refresh the that table and it works fine so it shouldn't be an user access problem.  I haven't been able to find anything online about it, it's very strange.  The linked table is in a database that is on a shared drive but again I refresh database tables from that shared drive all of the time without issue unless there's linked table involved.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

So right after I posted this I figured it out, hours of my time spent and it ended up being the most irritating thing.  I had mapped the drives under the mapped letters in the databases instead of the actual address on the server.